# How do I enable DAC on a clustered SQL Server 2008 after I can no longer connect to SQL Server in any other way

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server-2008, windows-cluster, windows

I'm having issues with SQLServer 2008 where a Server level triggered was not dropped correctly.

Articles on the web recommend dropping them through the DAC.

However, the DAC is disabled by default on Clustered environments.

How do I enable the DAC bearing in mind that I can no longer connect to the SQLServer 2008 instance in any other way.

cheers

andy

Answer (score 2):

To enable DAC, you need to run the following SQL command against your server:

```
sp_configure 'remote admin connections', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
```

If you can't connect to it to even run this though, you will most likely need to start your server in single-user mode (or possibly minimal configuration mode) and go from there. To do this, you stop your SQL Server, then run it from the command line with either the `-m` option (single-user mode) or the `-f` option (minimal configuration mode, which also enables single-user mode). You should be able to drop the triggers from there, or enable DAC from there, whichever you are more comfortable with.

[sqlserver command line reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190737(v=SQL.100).aspx)
[single user mode reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188236(v=SQL.100).aspx)